# Multiple possible exact paths in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Im using React Router with a Switch statement. Is there a way I can have multiple exact paths?

In this example id like the Table component to be loaded when the path is "/" or "/show" but not for any other paths.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=>{
          return <Table shows={this.state.shows} />
        }}/>
        <Route exact path="/show/*" component={Show} />
        <Route component={FourOhFour} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I believe the way you would want to do this would be to . move the `<Table />` route directly into the component that you want it to load in. So I believe a slight shift in perspective should take place. 

You would add `<Table />` into the component that you know will load with `/` or `/show` rather than saying `don't show here`

Comment: wont simply adding multiple ```<Route>``` component with the same component props be enough? ```<Route exact path="/" component={Table} /> <Route exact path="/show" component={Table} />```

Comment: @ReiDien Yes but it feels messy to repeat myself in this way.

Comment: you can use map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of paths in your `Route`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/(|show)' render={()=>{
          return <Table shows={this.state.shows} />
        }}/>
        <Route exact path="/show/*" component={Show} />
        <Route component={FourOhFour} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Edit: Updated code to take care of the warning.

Comment: This works but im getting an error in my console: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` of type `array` supplied to `Route`, expected `string`.

Comment: Updated the code for a fix for now. But I think they are about to allow arrays without a warning . Check https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5393